# Where do I find the keymap for linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

Let I have all my keycodes. If I want to look up my ascii character for 'a' which would be scancode 30 on press, this translates to 0141 via keymap. Where do I find this keymap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard scancodes are available [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html).